# Importing .jar in Android project causes Binary XML file line Error

Tags: android, jar, picker

I'm trying to implement other person library into my project. I've downloaded source from GitHub, have created .jar from the library project, have import it into sample project, and
it works fine, all call.

Now, I've added same .jar in same manner into my project, and when I call the
object in XML I get this:

/AndroidRuntime(983): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker

When I try to open .xml within my project from .jar file I'm not able to to that (maybe that is ok, I've never tried so far, so).

I've read few solutions here and tried to change my .xml view into:

```
<view class="net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker$number_picker"
    android:id="@+id/npAge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But same, app crashes.

questions>

1. is .jar file enough if built properly, or should "source" be imported somehow?
2. What's the proper way to export/import someones code into your project. I assumed creating .jar and adding to libs folder is proper way, but now I do not understand this missing .xml

As you can see is well known thing, simonvt Number picker, so I assume I'm not the first one trying to import it.

Tnx for help.

EDIT 1:
OK, seems that whether you link a .jar or link project as "library" project, you have to copy certain layout .xml from library to main project, and then it kinda work, but freezes the app. It displays and then you can see dialog freezes and new system dialog pops with message wait / stop the app.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the github project your referring to needs to be imported as an Android library project.

Basically, you cant just build a .jar file from the library source, as the Android build tools cant see the resources (the files in the res/ directory).

What you need to do is to reference the library as an **Android Library project**. This is easy to do, just follow the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

For more info on Library projects in general, check out: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: Tnx for link. I did that, so I now use linked Library project, but the problem remains with very same error. I don't get it.

Comment: This link was very helpful and your explanation is very helpful. Thank you. Indeed referencing the library as an Android Library project were steps in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source for the library code you put it in a separate Android project, and designate it as a library project (there is a checkbox to do so when creating the project).  Then import the the library project into your project by going to to your project's Proprties -> Android, selecting add library (near bottom) and selecting the library project you created.

Answer (score 0):

After the research and readings here, it seams that I must copy all the XML files to my project. So when I copied the XML it resolved the issue. I must admit I do not understand that, because in sample project that is clearly not the case, but I do not have issue any more so..